# Set larger width than 500px of tooltip in extjs grid cell

Tags: javascript, css, extjs

i have a grid cell with a very very large text inside.
I want a tooltip which shows the whole text, but the tooltip is everytime only 500px large and cuts the text of.

Here you can see a fiddle with very large phone numbers. It only works when you click on the cell.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/3jds&view/editor

Do you have an idea how i can change the width of this tooltip to show the whole phonenumber text?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add an override to your app to apply a new value for the `maxWidth` of the QuickTip.

```
Ext.define('Fiddle.override.tip.QuickTip', {
    override: 'Ext.tip.QuickTip',
    
    maxWidth: null
});
```